# How to determine the relation between the size of a maximum matching and a maximum independent set in a tree?

Tags: graph-theory, matching-theory

Let T be a tree, M a maximum matching, and $\alpha(T) = k$. Find a relation between $|M|$, $|V(T)|$ and $k$.

---

After drawing many small trees I always find $|M| = |V(T)| - k$, but I have no idea how to proof that this is indeed the relation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By [Kőnig's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C5%91nig%27s_theorem_(graph_theory)), $|M|$ is also equal to $\beta(T)$: the size of a minimum vertex cover of $T$. (This is true more generally in any bipartite graph).

It's true that $\alpha(G) + \beta(G) = |V(G)|$ in any graph $G$. In fact, more is true:

- an independent set includes *at most one* endpoint of each edge, and
- a vertex cover includes *at least one* endpoint of each edge,

so the complement of any independent set is a vertex cover, and vice versa.

Putting these together, if $G$ is a bipartite graph with maximum matching $M$, we have $\alpha(G)+ |M| = |V(G)|$.